# How do I Dockerize an R Shiny app on my local machine using Shiny server?

Tags: r, amazon-web-services, docker, shiny

The product pipeline I'm trying to accomplish is:

- Building a Shiny app on my local machine
- Dockerizing the Shiny app using Shiny server
- Pushing these containers to AWS

Currently, I run `Rscript` at the end of my Dockerfile, using `shiny::runApp()` to run the app. I can push this container to AWS, and I can access the app just fine. However, the Shiny app grays-out very quickly (e.g., upon inactivity, switching tabs in the browser, switching windows). My users often are switching from using the app to checking their email and back; the apps shut down in that time.

I have a strong background in R and statistical programming, but not much on the DevOps side. I have seen a lot of people showing how to install Shiny server on a Docker container using Docker repositories such as `rocker/shiny`. However, I have not been able to piece together all of these tutorials to address my entire workflow. I can get Shiny server working via running `docker run --rm -p 3838:3838 rocker/shiny`, but cannot figure out how to (a) get local apps working on that and (b) building containers that run my apps using Shiny server so that I can push these to AWS.

How do I Dockerize an R Shiny app on my local machine using Shiny server so that I can push this container to AWS so that my app can be run on AWS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Dockerfile should look like this:

```
FROM rocker/shiny

RUN install2.r <package1> <package2> ....

COPY <app/directory> /srv/shiny-server/
```

Build and run this image locally. If it works, you can deploy it to AWS the same way you are deploying the Shiny image.

Comment: Bingo, thanks. I did this, built it by `docker build -t testing .` and then ran `docker run --rm -p 3838:3838 testing` and got to my app, not the Shiny server index page that I had always been getting.